# How to fix my ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I've got a WordPress website I've been working on for a project of mine, the website is not nearly finished, On the website I have a button "Create A Clan" Which uses Visual composer (A plugin) I've reached out to WP Support with no aid, When I click on the "Create A Clan" Button, The visual composer just loads, and loads. I hit "F12" To try to see what is going on, and I have this error in the panel.

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   this.activities_list[i].call(window);
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined(anonymous function) @ VM922:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM921:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM921:816InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM921:682.

I have no idea what the above means. It tells me that the error is inside of my "vc_Page_Editable.js" folder, within my theme. On line 292.

```
   window.vc_google_fonts();
this.collectScriptsData();
this.loadInlineScripts();
this.loadInlineScriptsBody();
for(var i in this.activities_list) {
   this.activities_list[i].call(window);
}
```

I can add the ENTIRE files contents if needed.

Comment: Could you dump the content of `this.activities_list`?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know what that means, I am an extreme beginner.

Comment: You have a property in activities_list, which has undefined value and not reference to a function. If you just print the, following statement you will get the values `console.log("i=" + i "::val=" + this.activities_list[i]);` Put this statement prior to `this.activities_list[i].call(window);`

Comment: @CuriousMind Did as you said, It still won't load, The previous error is removed, though it now gives this one, "SyntaxError: Unexpected string"  console.log("i=" + i "::val=" + this.activities_list[i]);

Comment: @FrankShearer add a `+` after `"i=" + i` , `console.log("i="+ i +"::val=" + this.activities_list[i]);`

Comment: @Hacketo Hmm.. It still say's the same thing =/

Comment: @FrankShearer about the Syntax Error ? nvm just call `console.log(this.activities_list);` before the for-loop and paste the result in your post. You need to tell us what's in this `this.activities_list`

Comment: @Hacketo I'll go do so now, as for telling you what's in the list, I'm not sure how to do that. >.<

Comment: It still says "ReferenceError i is not defined" I took a screen shot of the console. http://i60.tinypic.com/2cgh5so.jpg

Comment: @FrankShearer replace the `console.log` with the one i tell you in my last comment.

Comment: @Hacketo Sorry, when putting it before the for-loop It still tells me that i is not defined, and above that it says Array[0]. (Copy and pasting) 
vc_page_editable.js:293 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
console.log(this.activities_list);
VM467:1 undefined
undefined
this.activities_list[i].call(window);
VM468:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined(anonymous function) @ VM468:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM466:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM466:816InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM466:682 That is the copy and paste of the log.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the list and one of the elements or properties in the list is undefined, so I would say safest bet is to check if that's the case and skip to the next element.

```
for(var i in this.activities_list) {
    if(!i || !this.activities_list[i])
        continue;
   this.activities_list[i].call(window);
}
```

Comment: why `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function this.activities_list[i].call(window);` and not `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`, if `this.activities_list[i]` was undefined, it would throw the second one

Comment: I've only just started working with codes a week ago, should I replace mine, with what you have posted?

Comment: @Hacketo Also `"Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined(anonymous function)"`

Comment: @FrankShearer yes, I say try it.

Comment: I would copy and paste the entire log where it shows that one error, but.. When I do that it fills the comment box with stuff, lol.